# What is the lowest altitude at which wyverns appear?

Tags: terraria

I'm starting a new (large) map, and I plan to build my palace in mid-air to better see the lands under my rule. I want to ensure that when I'm relaxing in my glass-bottomed swimming pool drinking a locally brewed artisanal mana potion I don't get attacked by marauding harpies and wyverns. What's the minimum height at which they appear/the maximum at which I can safely reside?

(I'm aware that having NPCs around will reduce the spawn-rate, but those shameless peasants don't get to live in the sky. They're not worthy.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Terraria Wikia, [Wyverns](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Wyvern) spawn above 800 feet above ground in all biomes except Hallow, where they spawn at just 300 feet.