# How do I defend against wyverns?

Tags: terraria

I have a sky house made out of hellstone, but the hard mode monsters like wyverns get in and kill me. How can I defend against them?

Comment: Floating houses should be built high enough so floating ground enemies (spectres and the like) cannot reach it but not high enough for wyvern to spawn. 15 tiles above ground level is a good starting point.

Answer (score 10):

There's no way to defend your house from the Wyvern, it can travel through blocks and no traps, even lava or spear traps, can kill it fast enough to prevent it entering the house.

However you can stop it from spawning which effectively solves the issue.

You can do any of the following to prevent the Wyvern from spawning:

- Build the house at a lower altitude. [See here for minimum spawning height](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/40810/106901)
- Have at least one town NPC near the player
- Make an artificial Crimson, Corruption or Dungeon Biome

Comment: Spear traps do 130 damage, whilst the wyvern has 8000 health, even taking into account the multi segmented nature of the wyvern, there's no way you could kill it before it would get into your house

Answer (score -3):

Just don't die to the wyvern.

Right before it hits you, jump (and hope you have a cloud in a bottle or rocket boots), and shoot at it as it passes under you.

If you don't have a gun, then just build your house lower. Repeat as long as necessary, and farm souls of flight while you are at it.